# Fetching data from second textbox

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I need to concatenate the value of textbox1 & 2 into textbox3 and hashing the value of textbox3 and show to textbox4 without refreshing any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

```
{{ Form::text('EmployeeID', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Employee ID', 'id'=>'txt_employeeID','required'=>'')) //textbox1

{{ Form::text('FirstName', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'First Name', 'required'=>'')) }} //textbox2

{{ Form::text('QRValue', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'txt_QRValue','onkeyup'=>'generate_qrcode(this.value)')) }} //textbox 3

{{ Form::text('HashedValue', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'readonly','id'=>'txt_QRHash')) }} //textbox4

$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#txt_employeeID').keyup(function() {
        $('#txt_QRValue').val($(this).val());
    });
});

function generate_qrcode(qrValue){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/qr/generator/getQRValueReg',
        data: {qrValue:qrValue},
        success: function(data){
            $('#QRresult').html(data.code);
            $('#txt_QRHash').val(data.codeHash);
        }
    });
}
```

textbox4 will only get the value of textbox3 if textbox3 is onkeyup, but what I need is to show to textbox4 what the value of textbox3 without keyup event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First give an id to your textbox2 as FirstName. Then, try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#txt_employeeID, #FirstName').keyup(function() {
        $('#txt_QRValue').val($('#txt_employeeID').val()+$('#FirstName').val());
    });
});
```

Then, to store the hashed value.

```
var qrvalue = $('#txt_QRValue').val();
var hashed_value = hash_function_you_are_using(qrvalue);
$('#txt_QRHash').val(hashed_value)';
```

inside the keyup function after the first statement

Answer (score 1):

If you only use `Jquery`, I think you must have an event to update value of `textbox4`. E.g.:

```
$("#textbox3").onChange();
$("#textbox4").pressKey();
```

Other way, you can use modal of angular to resolve it.